# BitmapFont - where is getBounds method in new 1.6 libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I download newest libgdx version 1.6 and i cant solve problem with center my BitmapFont text. Earlier in version 1.54 i used getBounds() method to find out width of text.

Share your solutions, thanks

Comment: You could just add the `getBounds()` function from [libgdx v1.5.5 BitFont.java](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/1.5.5/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/BitmapFont.java)

Comment: http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3658

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There was a post explaining the changes, but is not easy to find. The link was on the 1.5.6 release changelog:
http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3666

And the link about changes in fonts was:
http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3658

```
private static GlyphLayout glyphLayout = new GlyphLayout();
private BitmapFont fontA = new BitmapFont(), fontB = new BitmapFont();

// Set text and font each time you want to calculate bounds.
glyphLayout.setText(fontA, "my string");
fontA.draw(batch, glyphLayout, x + glyphLayout.width / 3, y + glyphLayout.height / 3);
y += glyphLayout.height;

glyphLayout.setText(fontB, "different font");
fontB.draw(batch, glyphLayout, x + glyphLayout.width / 3, y + glyphLayout.height / 3);
```